# Influx of "quickbooks" promotional "questions"

Tags: discussion, spam

I've noticed that there's been an influx of "quickbooks" promotional "questions" lately, usually all bearing similar text. I don't have an example, because they all seem to be flagged, downvoted, and subsequently deleted fairly quickly. Is there a "spam detector" in place to catch things like this?

Comment: Are you talking about these questions: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=quickbooks
If so, then yes, there is spam detector in place catching these.

Comment: SO is always under attack. The amount of stuff that's snuffed before any human sees it is astounding. Now if only it could track the spammers back to the source and send [Carl by to discuss drapes or something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(character))

Comment: Do read [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) over on the Uber Meta.

Comment: It's not catching them very well today.

Comment: I've seen about 10 today

Comment: Now they've switched from QuickBooks to Delta Airlines Reservations.